# Finding the limits for a double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

**Question:** Find the area enclosed by the two curves $y = x^2$ and $y = x^4$ using a double integral.

**My attempt:** I believe the limits would be $A$ = {$(x,y): -1 \lt x \lt 1,  x^4 \lt y \lt x^2$}

This is because the graph y=x^4 is smaller during the interval $-1 \lt x \lt 1$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct so far. The situation looks indeed like this graphically:

[image]

Your next step is to write the corresponding double integral, and calculate it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand how to calculate it after this step :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's correct, and note that:
$$
\int_{-1}^1\int_{x^4}^{x^2}dydx=\int_{-1}^1(x^2-x^4)dx=\int_{-1}^1x^2 dx-\int_{-1}^1x^4dx
$$
where the last integral is the difference of the areas under the two curves.